# Names of Moshiach

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach, messiah

One of the more well-known appellations in תנ"ך that describes משיח is צמח (Zach 3:8, 6:12; Isaiah 4:2; Jeremiah 23:6), with the English definition a variation of "Branch" (capitalized as refers to his name). 
Interestingly, there are quite a number of other descriptions in תנ"ך that are highly related and nearly synonymous, all revolving around matters of planting, growing, blossoming, sprouting and so forth.

צמח: The Branch
ויצא חטר: A shoot shall grow
ונצר משרשיו יפרה: A twig shall sprout from his stock
שרש ישי: stock of Jesse
ראש יניקותיו: top of the young twigs

I just wanted to know if anyone ever saw any commentary about משיח being associated with "growth" and the like?

I also ask for another specific reason, as follows:

Targum Onkelos renders the Aramaic translation of most variants of the root "משח" as "רב", which is "greatness". Since variants of "רב" can also mean growth, growing, etc (thus a child is called רביא), I wondered if there were any known commentary attempts to associate these facts.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to go to Aramiac. "**רְבָבָ֗ה כְּצֶ֤מַח הַשָּׂדֶה֙** נְתַתִּ֔יךְ וַתִּרְבִּי֙ וַֽתִּגְדְּלִ֔י וַתָּבֹ֖אִי בַּעֲדִ֣י עֲדָיִ֑ים שָׁדַ֤יִם נָכֹ֙נוּ֙ וּשְׂעָרֵ֣ךְ צִמֵּ֔חַ וְאַ֖תְּ עֵרֹ֥ם וְעֶרְיָֽה"

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answers your question:

**Malbim** writes on the verse "כֹּה־אָמַ֣ר ה' לִמְשִׁיחוֹ֮ לְכ֣וֹרֶשׁ אֲשֶׁר־הֶחֱזַ֣קְתִּי בִֽימִינ֗וֹ לְרַד־לְפָנָיו֙ גּוֹיִ֔ם וּמָתְנֵ֥י מְלָכִ֖ים אֲפַתֵּ֑חַ לִפְתֹּ֤חַ לְפָנָיו֙ דְּלָתַ֔יִם וּשְׁעָרִ֖ים לֹ֥א יִסָּגֵֽרוּ׃" ([Yeshayahu 45:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.45.1?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Malbim_Beur_Hamilot_on_Isaiah.45.1.1&lang2=bi)):

> למשיחו. ע''י משיחה היו מיחדים אותו לאיזה התמנות של גדולה, הכהן המשיח, יען משח ה' אותי לבשר ענוים :

Translation: Through the anointing [meshicha] they would set him apart towards a kind of appointment of greatness, the anointed priest, "Because the LORD has anointed me; He has sent me as a herald of joy to the humble".

**Metzudat Tzion** on the same verse:

> "למשיחו. הוא ענין גדולה ורוממות וכן נתתיה למשחה"

Translation: To His anointed one - this is a context of greatness and majesty, "I grant them to you and to your sons as a perquisite". (See also Metzudat Tzion on [Daniel 9:24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.45.1?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Metzudat_Zion_on_Daniel.9.24.5&lang2=bi))

**Rashi** on the verse "וּבִגְדֵ֤י הַקֹּ֙דֶשׁ֙ אֲשֶׁ֣ר לְאַהֲרֹ֔ן יִהְי֥וּ לְבָנָ֖יו אַחֲרָ֑יו לְמָשְׁחָ֣ה בָהֶ֔ם וּלְמַלֵּא־בָ֖ם אֶת־יָדָֽם׃" ([Shemot 29:29](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.29.29?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.29.29.2&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en&p4=Numbers.18&lang4=en&aliyot4=0)):

> למשחה. לְהִתְגַדֵּל בָּהֶם, שֶׁיֵּשׁ מְשִׁיחָה שֶׁהִיא לְשׁוֹן שְׂרָרָה, כְּמוֹ לְךָ נְתַתִּים לְמָשְׁחָה (במדבר י"ח), אַל תִּגְּעוּ בִּמְשִׁיחָי (דהי"א טז):

Translation: למשחה means to be raised to dignity by means of them. For sometimes the word משח is used in the sense of “dignity”, as in (Numbers 18:8), “to thee I have given them as a dignity (למשחה)”, and (I Chronicles 16:22) “Touch ye not my nobles (משיחי)”.

**Metzudat David** on the verse "אַֽל־תִּגְּע֥וּ בִמְשִׁיחָ֑י וְ֝לִנְבִיאַי אַל־תָּרֵֽעוּ" ([Tehillim 105:15](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.105.15?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en)):

> במשיחי. ר"ל בגדולי ובנסיכי וכן למשיחי לכורש.

Translation:
My anointed ones - meaning to say, My great ones and My princes, as it is said "to Cyrus, My [His] anointed one". (See also [Rashi on the verse](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.105.15?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Psalms.105.15.1&lang2=bi))