# Moshiach and Targum

Tags: messiah, targumin

Please allow me to briefly provide background information.

Please also note that [Zeke B.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/114554/1739) and others touch upon similar subject matter but contain distinct questions.

The word משיח is rendered by תרגום as רבא. For example, when the תורה speaks about כהן המשיח, the translation rendered by אונקלוס is כהנא רבא. Although משיח means "anointed" the term is often used to refer to an individual to whom הקב"ה grants greatness and kingship, hence רבא, which means "greatness" in Aramaic. Thus, משיח is rendered by אונקלוס as רב and variants (רבא ,רבו ,רבה).

Continuing with the background information, there are numerous locations throughout תנ״ך where משיח is called צמח or other terms that are roughly synonymous (i.e. חוטר and שרש are but two examples). It appears as though צמח is also rendered in תרגום as רב or a variant of that root.

Now to the actual question.

As is known, תרגום is central to enlightening us regarding the meaning of the biblical text.

With that in mind, I was wondering, what names could be related to צמח so that they would fit as a substitute or replacement for the actual word צמח (as per the various verses, i.e. הנה איש צמח שמו, etc. etc.).

For example, גידל and פרץ seem potentially related to the definition of צמח.

While not implying any connection to the ultimate משיח chosen by הקב"ה, and while the name is a nickname (not a primary name), could רובי (as is the name of Israel's current president, be a variant of צמח?

It would be especially interesting given how משיח is rendered by תרגום (as רב and variants of that root)

In a nutshell, the question is twofold:

(1) what names could be related to צמח?
(2) in particular, is the word רובי related?

I want to reiterate  that I completely  understand that (i) the names given for משיח are not necessarily names per say but rather descriptive terms regarding virtues or other identifying characteristics.  I fully recognize that. Furthermore,  I mentioned רובי as being the name of the president of Israel only for reference sake, not for any political reason as someone commented. Not at all! In conclusion, I'd still love to hear what names, titles or terms may be relates to the words צמח (or צמיחה). Again, since תרגום renders משיח as רב, it would be interesting if צמח was also connected to that same root (ריבה, רבה, רובי, רוביה, and so on). Thanks!

P.S. For an informative and thorough overview regarding אונקלוס, please see following link:

[www.etzion.org.il/en/lecture-1-targum-onkelos](http://www.etzion.org.il/en/lecture-1-targum-onkelos)

Comment: The part about Israel's president seems too political for this site.

Comment: I don't think there is a trivial connection between the name of *mashiach* and who *mashiach* is going to be. So when the gemara/medrash says names for *mashiach* it is a description of his inner essence, not his actual name.

Comment: רובי is his nickname. His name is ראובן.

Comment: I completely understand that (i) names on משיח are not necessarily names per say but descriptive terms regarding virtues or identifying characteristics. Furthermore, I mentioned רובי as being the name of the president of Israel only for reference sake, not for any political reason as someone commented. Not at all! In conclusion, I'd still love to hear what names, titles or terms may be relates to the words צמח (or צמיחה). Again, since תרגום renders משיח as רב, it would be interesting if צמח was also connected to that same root (ריבה, רבה, רובי, רוביה, and so on). Thanks!

Comment: As noted by @msh210, רובי is Rivlin's nickname. It's short for ראובן (Reuven), and he's not the only person called Reuven to have the nickname Ruvi.

Comment: Moving beyond that Rivlin comment and considering the broader question, would anyone know of any names that would be synonymous, related, or even translated as (in aramaic) ..צמח?